# Omit certain sequence of characters using Regex

Tags: regex

I need a regular Expression to get a string in between `<ul> and </ul>` tag...
But the thing is if there is one "`<ul></ul>`" tag inside the `<ul>` tag then regex stops with the inner  tag...But i need the entire string between the outer two  tags...
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't try to parse arbitrarily nested HTML using regex. [It won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/362634). Use a proper HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
String text = "<ul>My list</ul>";

String text1 = text.replaceAll("</?ul>", "");
                                  ^
                                  ? says / one time or none at all
                                  So it will take out <ul> and </ul>
```

This is java language by the way. The regex may work in different languages

Answer (score -1):

it will pick everything between from the first <ul> to the last </ul>.

```
<ul>(.*)</ul>
```